# PHP - put the student name and grade into suitable skill name

Tags: php, html, mysql

(1) **class**
[image]
(2) **studentmark**
[image]
(3) **skill**
[image]

**PHP code:**

```
    <?php
    //DB CONNECTION

    //---(1)Get skillname---
    $q = "SELECT skillName FROM skill ORDER BY skillName asc";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $skills[] = $row['skillName'];
    }

    //---(2)Get classname---
    $q1 = "SELECT className FROM class";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);
    $num_rows1 = mysqli_num_rows($r1);
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($r1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $className[] = $row1['className'];
    }

    //---(3)Create table---
    echo '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center">';
    echo '<tr>';
    for($a = 0; $a < $num_rows; $a++)
    {
        echo '<th colspan="2">'.$skillName[$a].'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    for($b = 0; $b < $num_rows; $b++)
    {
        echo '<th>Student Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Grade</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    //---(4)Get student name and grade---
    for($s = 0; $c < $num_rows1; $c++)
    {
          $q2 = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sm.studentName) as studentName,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(sm.studentGrade) as studentGrade,
                        s.skillName
                 FROM studentmark sm
                 LEFT JOIN skill s ON sm.skillID = s.skillID
                 WHERE sm.className = '".$className[$c]."'
                 GROUP BY s.skillID";
          $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);
          $num_rows2 = mysqli_num_rows($r2);

          $value = array();
          while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
              $value[] = $row2;
          }

          echo '<tr>';
          for($d = 0; $d < $num_rows2; $d++)
          {
               echo '<td>'.$value[$d]['studentName'].'</td>';
               echo '<td>'.$value[$d]['studentGrade'].'</td>';
          }
          echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

**From above code, my output is below:**

[image]

I am almost finished. I can show the student name and grade in 1 row.

Now, the last thing I want to do is put them into suitable skill name like below:
[image]

I want to compare the `$skills` and `s.skillname` on `$q2`.

**Below is my logic:**

```
    if($value[X]['skillName'] == $skills[X])
    {
         //put student name and grade inside
    }
    else
    {
         //empty cell
    }
```

But I don't know where should I open for loop and put my logic in (4). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm definitely messing up your nice clean code for the sake of not looping through the data multiple times. I also display the classnames cause that seems like useful info.

I changed some variable names cause I found it easier to remember what each variable was for. Also, note how the student info query is only executed once. Normaly (read: I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't but I'm CMA), you want to minimize the number of times you query the database

The code below will replace the entire script you posted.

```
<?php
//DB CONNECTION
$dbc = // magic connection sauce you already have

// get skills and stash how many there are
$q_class = "SELECT skillName FROM skill ORDER BY skillName asc";
$r_class = mysqli_query($dbc, $q_class);
$num_skills = mysqli_num_rows($r_class);
// start table code so that we can echo the skillname headers
echo '
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan=2>Classes</th>';//header for class name column
$header = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_class, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $skills[] = $row['skillName'];
    // store both thead rows at the same time so that we can echo them out properly later
    $header['first'][] = '
            <th colspan="2">' . $row['skillName'] . '</th>';
    $header['second'][] = '
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Grade</th>';
}
echo '
        ' . implode($header['first']) . '
        </tr>
        <tr>' . implode($header['second']) . '
        </tr>';
// clean-up
mysqli_free_result($r_class);

// get class names and stash how many there are
$classes = array();
$query_class = "SELECT className FROM class";
$r_class = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_class);
$num_classes = mysqli_num_rows($r_class);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_class, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $classes[] = $row['className'];
}
// clean-up
mysqli_free_result($r_class);

echo '
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

// pull query out of loop so that you'll only have to execute it once.
$studentInfoQuery = "
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(sm.studentName) as studentName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sm.studentGrade) as studentGrade,
    s.skillName,
    sm.className
FROM studentmark sm
LEFT JOIN skill s ON sm.skillID = s.skillID
GROUP BY sm.className,s.skillID";
$r_students = mysqli_query($dbc,$studentInfoQuery);
$num_studentRows = mysqli_num_rows($r_students);
$studentRows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_students, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // with our query, we only find 1 cell-pair per skill per class
    $studentRows[$row['skillName']][$row['className']] = '
            <td>' . $row['studentName'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['studentGrade'] . '</td>';
}
// everybody do their share! // actually, more clean-up
mysqli_free_result($r_students);

for($j = 0; $j < $num_classes; $j++) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <th>" . $classes[$j] . "</th>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_skills; $i++) {
        // always echo out a cell, even if we have student info for it
        // example: if(isset($studentRows['Listening']['1A'])) echo it out else echo cell
        if(isset($studentRows[$skills[$i]][$classes[$j]]))
            echo $studentRows[$skills[$i]][$classes[$j]];
        else
            echo "
            <td colspan=2>No skill-class-student value</td>";
    }
    echo "
        </tr>";
}

echo '
    </tbody>
</table>';
?>
```

Results:

[image: Results of code]

Comment: $studentRows[$row['skillName']][$row['className']] can write in array instead of td?

Comment: @KKLMichael what do you mean "write in array instead of td"?

Comment: I want this line $studentRows[$row['skillName'][$row['className']] = '<td>'.$row['studentName'].'</td><td>'.$row['studentGrade'].'</td>'; become $studentRows[$row['skillName']][$row['className']][] = array($row['studentName'],$row['studentGrade']); Can I?

Comment: @KKLMichael You can use my code as you wish, of course. Why do you need this change?

Comment: @KKLMichael well yes, you can make that change. Just be aware you'll have to modify the display code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine(although the things can be optimized) up to the last loop of step 4 in your design.

The problem you face right there is that you have a set of results which represent each class in it's rows. Now you need to spread them out in to skill table, importantly, without leaving vertical gaps.

The solution is to do it in a two dimension array in the memory and then create the table from it - because each cell in the memory is easily addressable than cells in an html table.

Memory table is going to be something like this:

```
|Skill 1 | Skill 2 | Skill3|
|stdnt 1 |stdnt 2,3|stdnt 4|
|        |         |stdnt 5|
```

Please note how I have used `array_search` to get the index of a particular skill and use it in `array_push` to insert the student in to the correct child array. Then I have just translated it in to an HTML table

I'm replacing your last loop with the following code:

```
//This is our memory table. Let's create it and add number of child arrays 
//equal to number of skills.
$memTable = array();    
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeOf($skills) - 1; $i++) {
    $memTable[$i] = array();
}

//Lets spread out your student information in to this 2d array now  
foreach ($value as $student) {

    //Get the index of the skill
    $skillIndex = array_search($student['skillName'], $skills);

    //Now go to appropriate child array and insert your student there
    array_push($memTable[$skillIndex], $student);        
};


//Lets create the table now

$emptyCount = 0;
$currentRow = 0;

//Do until all the skill arrays are empty for a row
while ($emptyCount < 3) {

    echo "<tr>";

    $emptyCount = 0;

    foreach ($memTable as $skillLevel) {

        if (sizeof($skillLevel) - 1 < $currentRow) {

            $emptyCount ++;

            echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";

        }
        else {

            echo "<td>" . $skillLevel[$currentRow]['studentGrade'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $skillLevel[$currentRow]['studentGrade'] . "</td>";  

        }
    }

    $currentRow++;

    echo "</tr>";
};
```

Please note that the skills will be rendered in the table according to the order they are in the $skills array. Please ask me questions if there is any place that is not clear to you. You might need to adjust some String names to adopt in to your code.

UPDATE

while ($emptyCount < sizeof($skills)) is more accurate.

Comment: I don't understand the $emptyCount in while($emptyCount) < 3.

Comment: Think about the point we are just ready to output the real html table. What is in the $memTable at this point? It is a collection of arrays who's lengths are varying. So, we are traveling through these set of arrays through a parallel path until we reach the point that all three arrays have no element for a particular element index. 

Arr1 => [x][x][x][x]
Arr2 => [x]
Arr3 => [x][x][x]

The loop should do only until the 4th element index for the above set of arrays. 

However in my code "while ($emptyCount < sizeof($skills))" is more accurate.

Comment: If I put while($emptyCount < $num_rows1) in my code, is it correct?

Comment: It should be while($emptyCount < $num_rows) in your code

Comment: You can prevent final "while" iteration from happening by checking all array elements against $currentRow and "break" the loop.